# How to plot complex plane?

Tags: complex-numbers

How to find complex numbers plane:
$$
|\bar z - i|\geq 2\\
\pi\leq \arg(z+i)\leq 2\pi
$$

I got it like that:
$$
|\bar z - i| = |z + i| 
$$
$$
 |z + i| \geq 2
$$
$$
 \sqrt{a +(b+1)} \geq 2
$$

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SE!

The circle is $|z+i|\le2$

Now all points with $\pi \le arg(z) \le 2\pi$ are points below the real-axis (Shaded in pink). Thus for $\pi \le arg(z+i) \le 2\pi$ we need to our origin to $(0,-i)$ and plot the same (Shown here in blue). 
[image]

For $|z+i|\ge2$ you need all points outside the circle and on the circle.
[image]

Comment: I made a mistake I need: |z + i| >= 2

Comment: I've made the changes for that case.

Comment: for 2 inequalities will there be all points in a semicircle?

Comment: No no! Outside the circle and coloured red!

Comment: thank you very much